# NSubstitute, assert on received calls, arguments is compared using object.ReferenceEquals

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nsubstitute

Please take a look at the following sample:

```
    public interface IDomainClass
    {
        int A { get; set; }
        void CalledMethod(IDomainClass data);
    }
    public class DomainClass : IDomainClass
    {
        public int A { get; set; }

        public void CalledMethod(IDomainClass data)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

And the following test:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestSample()
    {
        //Arrange
        IDomainClass testingClass = Substitute.For<IDomainClass>();

        IDomainClass data = new DomainClass() { A = 123, };
        IDomainClass expectedResult = new DomainClass() { A = 123, };

        //Act
        testingClass.CalledMethod(data);

        //Assert
        testingClass.ReceivedWithAnyArgs(1).CalledMethod(null); //ok
        data.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expectedResult);              //ok
        testingClass.Received(1).CalledMethod(expectedResult);  //fail
    }
```

The problem is that I don't know how to test the arguments in the received call (CallMethod). As it is, the arguments is compared using first object.ReferenceEquals and then object.Equals, and since I usually don't have control over the delivered data to the method, the objects (data and expectedResult) never references the same object.

However, there is a way to make it work, and that is if I override Equals, like this:

```
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return this.A.Equals((obj as DomainClass).A);
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.A.GetHashCode();
        }
```

This will work, but I don't want to implement Equals to satisfy a test since it will have all kind of other implications not worth mentioning here.

What I want is a comparer doing the same a the second assert line:

```
data.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expectedResult);
```

But this is not supported per default.

So, how do I solve this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSubstitute doesn't have fully-baked support for this at the moment (v1.10). [Issue 160](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/160) has some discussion of this.

One option as David Osborne mentioned is to catch the arguments and assert on them using your assertion library of choice.

Another is to use a custom argument matcher. I've included an example from [this comment](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/160#issuecomment-52718892):

```
[Test]
public void UsingArgMatcher() {
    var repos = Substitute.For<IRepos>();

    var sut = new SomeService(repos);
    sut.Process();

    repos.Received().Save(Arg.Is(EquivalentTo(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 })));
}

private Expression<Predicate<IEnumerable<T>>> EquivalentTo<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) {
    return x => Equiv(enumerable, x);
}

private bool Equiv<T>(IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b) { ... }
```

As described in the comment, this works but has problems with providing a pretty terrible error message when it fails.

There is also an example of [hooking NSubstitute up to FluentAssertions](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/160#issuecomment-53013051).

Comment: Well, I agree, the error message is not pretty, but it is a work-around and will do for now until a better implementation is released...

Answer (score 1):

You can store what's passed and then compare later:

```
[Test]
public void TestSample()
{
    //Arrange
    IDomainClass testingClass = Substitute.For<IDomainClass>();

    IDomainClass data = new DomainClass() { A = 123, };

    IDomainClass methodReceievedThis = null;

    testingClass
        .When(t => t.CalledMethod(Arg.Any<IDomainClass>())
        .Do(p => methodReceievedThis = p);

    //Act
    testingClass.CalledMethod(data);

    //Assert
    testingClass.ReceivedWithAnyArgs(1).CalledMethod(null); //ok

    methodReceievedThis.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(data);
}
```

Comment: That's true, but then I will still don't know whether CalledMethod did receive a call with the exact arguments or not, right...!

Comment: Within the context of the test you do because `methodReceivedThis` can only be set by a call to `CalledMethod()`.

Comment: If I already knew the result, then I wouldn't have to test for it, right :-) Obvious, in the real world, I would not know what a method - that calls another method, that maybe calls yet another method - would deliver to that method and that's why I test for what arguments I would expect it to receive.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem, this solved it for me:

```
[Test]
public void TestSample()
{
    //Arrange
    IDomainClass testingClass = Substitute.For<IDomainClass>();

    IDomainClass data = new DomainClass() { A = 123, };

    //Act
    testingClass.CalledMethod(data);

    //Assert
    testingClass.Received(1).CalledMethod(Arg.Is<DomainClass>(x => x.A == 123));  //this worked for me
}
```